# getting rid of sockets undefined errors in socket.io node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I sometimes get into errors of sockets undefined when trying to emit messages to sockets. I have kept a track of open sockets in an array, but still sometimes after a disconnection event is a messages is sent to it before it gets deleted in the array(like is some milliseconds, which is rare) i get this error:

```
io.sockets.sockets[receiverssocket2].emit('notifications',
                                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
```

For example when a client's socket is open i send back the socket id to the client

```
socket.on('set username', function(userName) {

  // do something here 
   io.sockets.sockets[socket.id].emit('setsocketid',
               {"source": socket.id
                 });
```

Now here, if the client opens the socket and closes it quickly i get the undefined error. ANy way to get rid of it?

Comment: Why could only you just check socket value and if it is undefined skip sending message?

Comment: you mean like io.sockets.sockets[socket.id]!= undefined?

Comment: Yes, before calling emit